# how does a system call work with linux and a programming lanugage except C

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I understand how a system call work in C with Linux. I want to know whether each programming language would have its own separate system library to communicate with the kernel.

> If yes should every programming language have its own system library
>   to work with the kernel?
>
> If No then how does a system call in another programming language work
>   in linux?

Comment: Other languages just call into C code AFAIK.

Comment: can you explain me a bit more clearly?

Comment: @Fazian : They use interpreters or compilers which are written in C, hence they can use components compiled from C.  So they do have their own libraries/modules/plugins whatever, and those are in part *wrappers* around the native C calls.

Comment: So if we call fork() in a c program and the suitable wrapper function for fork in another programming language, eventually is it the same fork() system call executes?

Comment: Several answers hint at a key point, which is that while the Kernel API may be a dialect of C, it is most often implemented with a mechanism and argument calling convention which is incompatible with that of the platform's C compiler, and thus requires assembly code to invoke.  The platform's C library will include wrappers which do this, and *most* other languages will use those along with many other parts of the C library, but technically a program is free to directly interact with the kernel or provide its own platform-dependent wrapper library which does so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C is pretty much the OS lingua-franca in the 21st century (in the sense that most mainstream operating systems are written mainly in C), many programming language implementations provide ways to call C code.  For example, Java has JNI, and both the Python and Ruby reference implementations (CPython and CRuby) provide the ability to create C extension modules, etc.

Most mainstream operating systems (including Linux) typically expose one or more low-level C APIs for doing things like interfacing directly with devices, spawning processes, etc.  Higher level languages can wrap these system calls and make them available at the language-level to the programmer.

Comment: SO there is only one specific system library for each OS?

Comment: Each OS typically exposes one or more low-level C APIs for doing things like interfacing directly with devices, spawning processes, etc.

Answer (score 2):

On AMD64 Linux system calls are accomplished by loading the appropriate registers and executing the `syscall` function.  On other architectures this is of course different.

Languages other than C must either make a foreign call to the C functions that make the system calls (which is usually easier and hence common), or make the system calls using the appropriate processor instructions as C does.

Answer (score 2):

System calls are a mechanism to execute kernel resident functions from user space.

The big picture view is that a system call is wrapped up in a user space function call, which accepts certain arguments from the user. These arguments are packed up into a structure, along with a code that indicates which kernel resident function to execute. The code then executes a CPU instruction which causes it's privilege level to rise to that of the kernel, while simultaneously executing a path of code that is now inside the kernel. This is called entering the kernel. This code inside the kernel has access to the data structure that was assembled for the system call. It locates the target code, sets up the arguments for the code from the structure, and makes the call. It collects the return code and arranges for it to be returned to the user space by traversing the path in reverse.

There are other things that happen along the way, like address space switching etc., but this is pretty much what happens conceptually.

[Here are some specific details.](http://articles.manugarg.com/systemcallinlinux2_6.html)

Answer (score 1):

In the Intel architecture any call into kernel-mode functionality involves an interrupt with some parameters (the system call number and other arguments in linux). If any programming language wants to utilize this it has to provide a construct which can be compiled into the right assembly (int 80 for example).

C and C++ provide this. Other languages compiling into native code can also be made to provide this. It is easier in general to call into C/C++ functionality by some means of RPC/COM calls.

Answer (score 0):

Most languages have some means to invoke C function calls underneath commonly referred to as `Foreign Function Interface`. I've listed few I've come across:

```
Java - JNI
Python, Ruby, Perl, TCL - have extensions for directly calling native C code. Python also provides `ctypes`
Microsoft's CLR - P/Invoke a mechanism to invoke native platform code
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all system calls use assembly  to call the kernel - the language that the CPU understands. C is compiled to assembly.  The system call on x86 is done with either int 0x80 or sysenter - both are assembly instructions executed by the CPU. The kernel itself is also compiled code. You have two types of languages compiled and interpreted.
The compiled languages are compiled to assembly - they can have a layer of own code in the language itself, kind of glue, that calls a c library with the syscall implementation or they can have own implementation of syscalls that compiles to assembly.
The interpreted languages are compiled code interpreter written in random language but compiled to something that runs on the CPU - they have the same two options, but in the interpreter - not in the byte code, not in the script code.